# Continuity in relation to integration

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

Let $f$ be integrable. I want to show there exist two functions $g$ and $h$ that are continuous under a closed interval $[a,b]$ s.t $h\leq f\leq g$.

What I've done: Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$ I tried to show that $|g(x)-g(x_0)| < \epsilon$ so I defined $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$,  $g(x) = f(x) + \delta$.
and then implemented the expression:

$$|g(x)-g(x_0)| = |f(x) + \delta - f(x_0) - \delta | = |f(x)-f(x_0)|$$

but it doesn't seem like I'm getting anywhere.

Would like to get some help,

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm discussing Riemann integrability

Comment: You are discussing Riemann integrability, right?

Comment: Yes I'll mention it

Comment: A function has to be bounded to be Riemann-integrable (else at least one of the upper or lower integrals diverges)

Comment: See, in your case it is very simple. Since $f$ is bounded, let it's upper bound be $M$ and lower bound be $m$. Now let $g(x) = M$ and $h(x) = m$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Then, $g,h$ are continuous, and $f$ is clearly between these. A more difficult proposition, is to show that $g,h$ can be arbitrarily close to $f$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг why the boundness of g and h in the closed interval implying they are continious. I think it's the other way around. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: It's not the boundedness of $g,h$ implying they are continuous. I have defined $g(x)=M $ and $h(x) = m$, so they are *constant* functions as well. That ensures they are continuous.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I want to prove your more difficult proposition, is to show that g,h can be arbitrarily close to f - I thought about defining h=g=minimum of f and then it's very simple but I can't because this way I forced f to be a constant which I cannot do. How would I define the functions to make it work?

Comment: For that, you operate as follows : You know we can bring step functions as close as we want to $f$. So all you need to prove is that if $f$ is a step function, then you can bring a continuous function as close to it  as you want, from above or below. To do this, you can think of "joining" the steps using straight lines, this will give a continuous function.